# How to convert "2019-02-10T19:30:00+00:00 " date format to "19:30"

Tags: android, kotlin

I am a new  android developer.
I would like to parse this date: 
2019-02-10T19:30:00+00:00
to this format 19:30 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(“yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS”);
Date sourceDate = null;
try {
sourceDate = dateFormat.parse(sourcedatevalue);
} catch (ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(“HH:mm”);
targetdatevalue= targetFormat.format(sourceDate);
```

You can use this template.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the format of your string would be xxxx-xx-xxxAB:CD:xx+xx:xx and you need AB:CD you can do this:

```
val stringToFormat = "2019-02-10T19:30:00+00:00"
val formattedString = stringToFormat.substring(11,16)
```

But the question should be more precise...

Answer (score 0):

You can use native SimpleDateFromat to parse such dates.

For example:

```
String yourTime = "2019-02-10T19:30:00+00:00";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    try {
        calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(yourTime));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
    System.out.println(output.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: You can also set the default timezone to UTC "TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC))" and interpret the input time with timezone like ""yyyy-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ssZ" in this case no need for calendar.setTimezone line.

Answer (score 0):

try this in kotlin:

```
 <your_date>.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT))
```

example output is

> 2:11 PM